# Driver for Mediatec 7610U wifi dongle in raspbian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, usb, driver, raspbian

I'm trying to compile driver for mt7610 ([Product Page](http://www.mediatek.com/en/products/connectivity/wifi/home-network/usb-dongle/mt7610u/)) usb wifi dongle in raspbian on raspberry pi 1 B+

[Here](http://cdn-cw.mediatek.com/Downloads/linux/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.tar.bz2) is the driver source code download link

After compiling and installing I get the fillowing in dmesg

```
[ 2013.724491] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[ 2013.841247] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=7610
[ 2013.841286] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2013.841306] usb 1-1.2: Product: WiFi
[ 2013.841323] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
[ 2013.841382] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 1.0
[ 2014.117654] mt7650u_sta: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

lsusb looks like this

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same wifi dongle and I was unlucky with installing any drivers the usual way on my Raspberry Pi 3. However, I found [this thread on official forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=107756&start=100) where [this script](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/install-wifi.tar.gz) by MrEngman is advised. Apparently, the script automatically finds the right driver for you and installs it. It worked for me.